# showDialog is rebuilding infinitely in flutter

Tags: flutter

The code below prints 'inside' infinitely until I close the Dialog. Does anyone know the reason?

Below code is inside a Stateful widget.

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      pagination();
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  void pagination() {
    var len =
        Provider.of<OrderHistoryData>(context, listen: false).allOrders.length;
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !Provider.of<OrderHistoryData>(context, listen: false).isLoading &&
        (len % 20) == 0 &&
        Provider.of<OrderHistoryData>(context, listen: false).next != null) {
      Provider.of<OrderHistoryData>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchMoreOrderHistory();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }
void showFullOrderDetails(ModelOrderHistory order) {
    print('showDialog');
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        print('inside');
        return Dialog(
          insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(31.11)),
          child: const Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 26),
            child: Text('sdf'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I have a List of orders that has a pagination. When I click one of the items, it shows full details about the order on a Dialog. However, I noticed that when I press order showDialog, it started rebuilding indefinitely for no reason. Only inside of showDialog is rebuilding.

Is it a bug in flutter?

Comment: From the examples [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html), I've tried adding a `print` statement right above the `return Dialog` and it only prints once. If it were related to how you call the `showFullOrderDetails` then it would print `showDialog` endlessly too, hmm.

Comment: I've added your functions to that examples directly, without using `ModelOrderHistory ` parameter and it works as intented. Could you try without the parameter?

Comment: yes, the text 'showDialog' is printed just once. The thing is builder inside the showDialog widget is building infinitely.

Comment: Also, I think they do `return` on `showDialog`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code above. I  just tried it on dartpad. and print once.
maybe the problem is from another method you called.

Comment: No there is no need for return. And removing parameters didn't work. Is it possible because of the stateful widget that is calling dialog?